How to configure second LAN-Port as Switch and a Static-DHCP-IP with Netplan?
I bought a device as a HomeServer that has two Gigabit ports.

Port 1 (enp1s0) is connected to a LAN cable that goes directly to the router.
Port 2 (enp2s0) is now to be connected to a Kyocera printer.

The device should now be configured as follows:

Port 1 (enp1s0): Fixed DHCP IP address 192.168.0.250.
Port 2 (enp2s0): Route all connections directly to the router so that the devices are assigned an IP address here via DHCP.

The router is listening on the IP 192.168.0.1. This is also the default gateway as well as the default nameserver.
I have already configured Netplan as follows:
/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:

        # LAN-Port 1
        enp1s0:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            wakeonlan: true
            addresses: [192.168.0.250/24]
            routes:
                - to: 192.168.0.1
                  via: 192.168.0.250

        # LAN-Port 2
        enp2s0:
            dhcp4: true

    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [enp1s0, enp2s0]
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true

netplan status

On a network scanner, following devices will be found:

The printer works perfectly here and can be reached from the entire network and is assigned a dynamic IP address by the router.
Problem

The device cannot be reached at the IP address 192.168.0.250.
Why is the IP address '192.168.0.28' given here (This is also not accessible)?
All services (for sample Apache2-Webserver, SSH-Daemon,.. are listened globally) cant be reached.


Remove the address on enp1s0; there's no reason for that address and route to exist.

Yes, they do exist: The Internet is connected via the router and the fixed IP 192.168.0.250 should be set here.

Not when it's part of a bridge. Once bridged, it is detached from the OS networking stack – it literally becomes a "switch port", while br0 is what connects the host OS to the "switch".

A switch only uses IP for its management (basically another host attached to the switch). Switches are transparent layer-2 devices.


The device cannot be reached at the IP address 192.168.0.250.

Bridged interfaces no longer process IP packets and therefore cannot have an IP address. In a sense, they are detached from the host OS and attached to the "switch" (bridge) that you've just created.
The "switch" has three ports: enp1s0 and enp2s0 connected to physical Ethernet, and br0 itself representing an equivalent of a "CPU port" in actual switches – the latter is what now connects the OS to the bridge, and only through the bridge to the LAN.
Any IP addresses (whether static or DHCP) therefore must be configured on the br0 interface instead. The host will appear to have br0's MAC address (and might therefore get a different DHCP lease than before), while the MAC addresses of individual ports are unused (except maybe for occasional STP/RSTP or LLDP).
(I'm guessing that the 192.168.0.250 address may still work for receiving packets after other devices realize that it is now on a different MAC address, but the next issue will still prevent it from responding.)

Why is the IP address '192.168.0.28' given here (This is also not accessible)?

You configured DHCP on br0, so br0 got an IP address via DHCP. (It's a different address than enp1s0 has because the MAC address and therefore DHCP Client-ID are different.)
It's not accessible likely because the OS still has a local subnet route via enp1s0 (because of the static IP address there), even though that interface can no longer send IP packets.
